# In Character Device Driver print statement executing infinite time in read method

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I'm writing basic device driver module for character device driver.
I want following behavior in that: When I will be reading from device file using `cat /dev/scull`, I should get, number of times the device is opened.
For that I am using variable count and increasing it when my open function is called. I'm storing this variable in private structure.
The problem I'm having is in read function

```
struct scull_dev{
    int x;              /*Private data members*/
    struct cdev cdev;   /*This is character device structure*/
};

ssize_t scull_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct scull_dev *dev = filp->private_data;

    pr_info("You have opened device %d times\n",dev->x);
    return sizeof(dev->x);
}
```

The print statement "You have read device %d times" is printing infinite times. I have to press `Ctr+D` to stop it.

I want output to go to cat as well as in log file.

Comment: In your description, you say "number of times device is _opened_", but your code prints "You have _read_ device %d times".  Which count do you want?  The "open" count or the "read" count?  And, `pr_info` will output to the system log file.  Is that what you want, or do you want the output to go to `cat`?  What is the struct definition for `scull_dev`? If you can answer these questions, I can post an answer for you as I already know why you're getting infinite output

Comment: Thanks @Craig I have updated the question. I want output to go to cat and also in log file.

Comment: Okay, you've got half of it, I'll code the rest.  Since you are _not_ incrementing `x` in your read function, to me, this means the count is the "open" count.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm incrementing x variable (used for open count) in open function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you were getting infinite output because you were always returning `sizeof`.  And, you had no code to copy data to `cat`.

Okay, I've coded up what I think you'll need [please pardon some gratuitous style cleanup].  Note: I've *not* built it.  I've annotated it a bit, so this should get you started:

```
struct scull_dev {
    int x;                              /*Private data members*/

    int rdpend;                         // 1=partial read in progress
    int bufoff;                         // current offset within buffer
    int buflen;                         // remaining length to transfer
    char buf[100];                      // buffer with text to output

    struct cdev cdev;                   /*This is character device structure*/
};

ssize_t scull_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count,
    loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct scull_dev *dev = filp->private_data;
    ssize_t curlen;
    long err;

    // NOTES:
    // (1) rdpend _must_ be cleared in the device close (and/or) device
    //     open -- we only want _one_ output line per invocation
    // (2) _after_ you get this working, you might move _this_ code block
    //     to the open routine (i.e. the rdpend would not be necessary)
    // (3) leaving it here makes the pr_info and cat output appear closer in
    //     time
    do {
        // only output a single line per open
        if (dev->rdpend)
            break;
        dev->rdpend = 1;

        dev->buflen = snprintf(dev->buf,sizeof(dev->buf),
            "You have opened device %d times\n",dev->x);
        pr_info("%s",dev->buf);

        dev->bufoff = 0;
    } while (0);

    // get length and handle user short read
    // [possibly less than we have--(e.g.) caller's count could be (say) 10
    curlen = dev->buflen;
    if (curlen > count)
        curlen = count;

    do {
        // nothing left to output
        if (curlen <= 0)
            break;

        err = copy_to_user(buf,dev->buf + dev->bufoff,curlen);

        // probably an access violation or segmentation fault, etc.
        if (err < 0) {
            curlen = err;
            break;
        }

        // creep through the buffer
        dev->buflen -= curlen;
        dev->bufoff += curlen;
    } while (0);

    return curlen;
}
```

Reminder: Don't forget to clear `rdpend` in your open and/or close.

Comment: Why `do...while` loop is required around `copy_to_user`. Can't we write all `dev->buf` data in single call of `copy_to_user`?

Comment: Note: `do { ... } while (0)` is a "once through" loop--a stylistic construct to avoid if-else ladders, etc. The real reason is mentioned above [in the comment block where `curlen` is being set].  The caller may ask for only a byte at a time (e.g.). Although unlikely [with cat], it still must be accounted for. (e.g.) if buflen is 40 but count is 20, curlen must be clipped to 20. In that case, the read routine will be called _again_ until the full count is fulfilled [possibly, multiple times]. (e.g.) Pgm does `read(fd,buf,1)` in a loop. if `char buf[1]` writing more is _bad news_ :-)

Comment: Value of count is depend on what factor? BTW Your code is working as my expectations. But I'm unable to understand, when I call `cat`on device file, why it shows infinite output.

Comment: Are you [still] getting infinite `pr_info` messages [or just one]? Describe the nature of the cat output (e.g. `cat /dev/sculldev > /tmp/out`) and what ends up in /tmp/out.  That is, message text repeats, or you get message followed by semi-trash binary chars, etc?

Comment: Value of `count` is from the [given] app's `read` syscall:  In app: `read(fdscull,xyzbuf,xyzlen)`.  In driver read: `buf` will be `xyzbuf` and `count` will be `xyzlen`